# For loop regression over a list of dataframes with multiple variables

Tags: r, for-loop, regression

Hello I need to know how to apply a for loop regression over separate dataframes. I started by making a list of dataframes

```
dflist = c(cvx,csco,trv,unh,gs,nke,v,aapl,wba)
```

The response variable is **ri_rf** and the explanatory variables are **smb,hml,capm**.

I've already calculated smb, hml, capm, ri_rf and have them laid out from stock 1 to stock 12. I just need to regress for each stock!

I need the equation

```
lm(ri_rf ~ smb, hml,capm)
```

Can someone please help me out!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Store the dataframes in a list and apply `lm` for each dataframe using `lapply` -

```
dflist = list(cvx,csco,trv,unh,gs,nke,v,aapl,wba)
result <- lapply(dflist, function(x) lm(ri_rf ~ smb + hml + capm, x))
```